# Rounding off values displayed on chart

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have a simple c3 chart with hard coded values.

This is my code for the chart I created

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Data A', 50],
            ['Data B', 50],
        ],
        type : 'donut'

    },

});
```

For some reason on my chart the value is displayed as 50.0%, i want it to display as only 50%. I want to round off my values to a whole number.

I even tried to do this `['Data A', Math.round(50)],` but with no luck. Please advice. HERE IS MY [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1u81yLn6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1u81yLn6/1/).

The key to this is that you have to format your output and not round your input.

```
donut: {
    label: {
        format: function (value) {
            return d3.format('.0')(value)+'%';
        }
    }
}
```

This code formats the given value as whole number and adds an "%" when added to your c3.generate param.

Comment: This is good but what if I have something like 50.5% and I still want to round it off?

Comment: I guess i would do  `return d3.format('.0f')(value)+'%';` right?

Comment: that's the way to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using d3.round(50) . This should be working .